# How can I get all history items related to a given message in Gmail API with Python?

Tags: python, gmail-api

How can I get all history items related to a given message in Gmail API with Python.

I query the message for the most recent historyid and query that but I can't seem to find history related to the message no matter what I try. Suggestions?

Comment: You can't get the history of a particular message. You can narrow it down to the history of a particular label, but that's it. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: My users sometimes say that messages just magically went to the trash. I'd like to be able to see the deletion events.

Comment: Fortunately G Suite recently solved this problem with post-delivery history.